# Login authentication to asp.net and postgresql

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql

I have tried to implement login page in ASP.NET Core MVC and using postgresql as database.

It should check whether user exits in the database table of postgresql and verify, so what is the query to search for user in database and made them sign in?

I have written my code like this:

```
public IActionResult Login(string seller_email, string seller_password)
{
    using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    connection.Open();

    string main_query = String.Format(@"select exists(select 1 from public.""sellers"" where ""seller_email""='{0}')", seller_email);

    using var command_main = new NpgsqlCommand(main_query, connection);
    int result_main = command_main.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (result_main < 0)
    {
        return View(nameof(Create));
    }
    else
    {
        return View(nameof(Sign));
    }
}
```

There is a `seller` table in the database, so just have to check seller exists or not - if exists the have to create a view for it

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a `select` query, so you must use a `command.ExecuteReader`.

The `ExecuteNonQuery` is to be used with statements that update/insert/delete records.

BUT, most importantly, don't concatenate user submitted values into the query string, as it opens the door to SQL injections. Instead, used a parameter.

See the [getting started](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html) doc for a simple example.